Installing/managing windows services in windowless Python exe
I have an application written in Python which installs and manages windows services. I've managed to get it all working up until the point where I use PyInstaller with the --noconsole option. The app works fine with the console, but I need it to work without one. In my current version, I install the service executable and then configure the service as follows:
    # Locate service executable
    service_executable = service_directory.parent / 'ar_service.exe'

    # Run service script as subprocess to install the service
    try:
        subprocess.run([str(service_executable), '--startup=auto', 'install'],
                       check=True)
    except Exception as error:
        logging.debug(f'\nERROR: Service failed to install; {error}\n')

    # Run sc command to configure auto-reset
    try:
        subprocess.run(['sc', 'failure', service_name,
                        'reset=86400', 'actions=restart/5000'],
                       check=True)
    except Exception as error:
        logging.debug(f'\nERROR: Failed to configure auto-restart; {error}')

I've spent a few hours reading online and trying solutions, but none of them have worked. I've tried using Popen and redirecting stdout, stdin and stderr, and I've tried the recipe given at https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-subprocess
Any suggestions?

So the recipe on github is outdated, needs tweaking for recent versions of Python; using .run with text=True should do the trick
